# how to custom jquery mobile on split button listview to 3 anchors?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I want to custom the jquery mobile on listview split button to 3 links for a list. http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/lists/lists-split.html

This is the example what i wanted :

[image]

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

I eventually had a to create a custom list with grid structures to get it just perfect.  It's not light code but more flexible. This is especially important as you support more and more devices. Take a look at the grid structures available to jquery mobile.
http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/content/content-grids.html

Answer (score -1):

Please find the below code for listview split button into 3 links.

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-split-theme="d" data-split-icon="check" >
<li>
 <a href="index.html">
  <img src="images/album-bb.jpg" />
  <h3>Test 1</h3>
 </a>

<a id="delete" data-icon="delete" class="ui-li-link-alt ui-btn ui-btn-up-c" data-transition="slideup" data-rel="dialog" href="lists-split-purchase1.html" title="Delete" data-theme="c" style="left: 939px;">
<span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-delete ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span>
</span>
</a>

<a id="edit"  data-icon="minus" data-transition="slideup" data-rel="dialog" href="lists-split-purchase2.html" title="Edit " data-theme="c">
</a>
</li>
</ul>
```